Including specific parts of lib.dom in a Typescript project
I have a Typescript project that runs in a limited environment that includes React but does not allow access to many common Window features. For example AudioBuffer is not something  users have access to (or want to use) and I do not want it showing up in intellisense autocomplete.
  "compilerOptions": {
    // DOM is required for React but includes _a lot_ of types
    "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM"],

I'd like to expose specific parts of Window (e.g. console and URLSearchParams) with something like this:
// pseudocode!
declare type global = Pick<lib.dom, "console" | "URLSearchParams"> 

The result is that users would see types for console and URLSearchParams types but AudioBuffer and friends included in the rest of the lib.dom definition.
